# list.index(' ') не находит элемент в списке

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, списки, index

Почему  `probel = new_list.index(' ')` не видит ни одного такого элемента в моем списке (хотя они есть)?

```
probel = new_list.index(' ')
```

> ```
> ValueError: ' ' is not in list
> ```

```
inp = list(input())
def delProbels(inp):
    new_list = inp
    print(new_list)
    count = 0
    while count <= len(inp)-1:
        probel = new_list.index(' ')
        new_list.pop(probel)
        count += 0
    print(new_list)        
delProbels(inp)
```

Comment: У Вас происходит попытка удалить из строки столько пробелов, сколько в ней символов всего. Попробуйте выводить `count` (правда, заменив на `count += 1` вместо нуля), увидите, что первый пробел удаляется нормально, а потом - ошибка (если пробел в стркое лишь один). Если строка состоит лишь из пробелов - ошибки не должно быть.

Comment: Ну я дурак. Забыл на +1 поменять count когда копировал со строки выше...спасибо. Заменил count и сделал len(inp)-2. Все работает. У меня пробел ровно через каждый элемент.

Comment: Если пробел всегда точно через каждый элемент, то и так сойдёт, наверное; более обще - можно использовать `new_list.count(' ')` для подсчёта пробелов в списке

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно регуляркой пробелы удалить=)

```
import re
text = 'Text text, text!'
text = re.sub(r'\s+', '', text)  # заменяем все пробелы на ничего  
print(text)  # out: "Texttext,text!"
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно через replace удалить, если регулярные выражения не знаете (но лучше сразу приучать себя к правильному):

```
>>> text = 'text text text'
>>> print(text.replace(' ', ''))
texttexttext
>>> text = 'text text       text'
>>> print(text.replace(' ', ''))
texttexttext
```